# Request matcher in spring security does not wrok

Tags: spring, spring-security

I need to customize the default login page provided by the Spring Security. So I specified the login page in security filter chain and permitted all for request `/loginpage` with request matcher. I am getting an error like too many redirects.

My security config file:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/loginPage").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/loginPage");

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

My controller code:

```java
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping("/loginpage")
    public ModelAndView loginpage(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView= new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("login.html");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView homepage(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView= new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("home.html");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a typo in `loginpage` and `loginPage` with P capital

Comment: You have a typo in your configuration. But you also have to permit `login.html` with Spring Security 6.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (P.S. handle exception more judiciously)

```java
        
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin(login -> {
                   try { login.loginPage("/loginPage").permitAll();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```